# Diffie Helman obtaining $g^y \bmod p$ from $g^{xy} \bmod p$ and $g^x \bmod p$

Tags: diffie-hellman, group-theory, number-theory

This may seem like a strange question. Lets say I have $g^x \bmod p$ and $g^{xy} \bmod p$. How can I efficiently obtain $g^y \bmod p$? I assume I must use modular inverse but I don't know where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Lets say I have $g^x \bmod p$ and $g^{xy} \bmod p$. How can I efficiently obtain $g^y \bmod p$?

We hope that there is no efficient method (without using knowledge of $x$ or $y$)

Here's why: if you can solve that problem, you can solve the (computational) Diffie-Hellman problem; here's how:

- Suppose that you did have an Oracle that, given $g, g^x, g^{xy}$, returned $g^y$
- Then, you can use that to create an Oracle that, given $h, h^x$, returned $h^{x^{-1}}$

  Here's how, you'd call your Oracle with $g=h, g^x=h^x$ and $g^{xy} = h$.  These conditions hold only if $x^{-1} = y$, and so when your Oracle returns $g^y$, that's also $h^{x^{-1}}$
- With that Oracle, you can generate a squaring Oracle (given $h, h^x$, return $h^{x^2}$, and with that, computing DH is straight-forward.

Comment: @mathman123123: I don't see how those modifications would change my answer; with the Oracle, it would still be able to compute unmodified DH, so unless you're in a group where DH was weak, it looks impossible